# How to learn REST and DAO with Scala?

Tags: scala

I am new in Scala and I would like to learn DAO and REST API.  Is there any good website, tutorials that can help me ? I would like a good tutorial that explains with good explanation for a beginner in scala.
I have imagine a library management project and I would to access the database with DAO and also  create an API.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your question requires a long response. I would recommend the following resources:

- Functional Programming with Scala course. There you will start to get used to the basic concepts working with Scala like high order functions, immutability, immutable collections(map, flatMap, filter, ...), pattern matching, basic generics and implicits, etc... That will help a lot when you start with a specific framework.
- For building your projects and manage dependencies: SBT, https://www.scala-sbt.org/learn.html.
- Once you get a little bit familiar with all of these concepts, you have several main options. If you come from a classic Spring+Hibernate background maybe Play Framework https://www.playframework.com/ that is build on top of Akka: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/introduction.html?language=scala.
- If you want to get deeper in functional programming read the red book: Functional Programming in Scala and try to start with abstractions: Monoid, Functor, Monad, Applicative ... A lot of Scala common frameworks work like Cats, Circe or Http4s are based on them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never used Spring + Hibernate, and I have never worked on DAO and REST API.

Comment: I´d suggest before building a REST api and database access get familiar with Scala fundamentals. You learn them in the first course.